# How to add a map as a class field?

Tags: python

I want to add a dictionary that maps an object to a list of objects as an instance variable to a class. What is the idiomatic way to do it in Python? Here's how I've done it:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myDict = { None : [None] }
```

Comment: @delnan I don't know, I'm fairly new to Python. If not for anything else, an idiom at least makes the declaration easily recognizable at a glance.

Comment: If that is all your class does, then you could just use a dictionary. I think we're missing the bigger picture here. Why do you want a class like that?

Comment: @Mattias You aren't actually asking me to show you the whole code, when only this simple example is all that is needed, are you?

Comment: @Paul: you don't have to show all your code to explain what you are trying to do.  In fact, please don't post all your code, only enough to explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already hit upon the idiomatic way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd do it this way, if you want the option of starting out with a certain number of objects, and you want it clearer what you're desiring.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, objlistdict=None):
        "Takes an optional initial dictionary with objects as keys and lists of objects as values"  # docstrings are very useful for documentation
        self.myDict = {} if objlist is None else objlist # sets `self.myDict` to be the initial dict, otherwise makes it an empty one
```

Note that the objects you use as keys do need to be hashable, and I believe it's recommended to use immutable objects even if the mutable object you're using still has a hash method defined, due to the fact that objects that compare equal are generally supposed to have the same hash, so changing something about the object will change the hash value, and that might cause problems with being unable to access the value for an original key.

Comment: in python, 'hashable' is usually a synonym for immutable, for exactly the reason that `dict` keys must be 'hashable'.  mutable but hashable keys cause `dict`s to misbehave in very strange ways.

Comment: `not obj` isn't an acceptable substitute for `obj is None`. It wrongly considers several non-`None` values `None`. Practical example why it matters here: providing an empty instance of a dict-like object (such as an `OrderedDict`) doesn't work with this code, it gets replaced by a normal empty dict.